# set buffer false during jQuery ajaxSubmit

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp-classic

I want to run ASPX page in ASP page.
So I use ajaxSubmit and print to "target div" get from ASPX page like this:

```
var data = new FormData();
 data.append("email", $("#EMAIL").val());
 data.append("pass", $("#PASS").val());
 data.append("store", $("#STORE").val());

 if ($("#STORE").val()!="" && $("#EMAIL").val()!="" && $("#PASS").val()!="") {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).ajaxSubmit({
         data: $(this).serialize(),
         target: "#formres",
          async: true,
          global: false,
          cache: false,
         beforeSubmit: function () {

         },
         success: function () {
             if($("#yu").val()!="yes")
             {
                 setTimeout(function(){
                     window.location.href = $("#yu").val();
                 },2000); 
             }

         },
         resetForm: false

     });
```

But anything display before process ends.
I think it must be something like "Response.Buffer=false" or "flush()" at jquery too.(I use  "cache: false," for this purpose)
I set Reponse.Buffer =false at asp and aspx page.
But it still not working. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Problem is not clear at all. What does *"but anything display before process ends"* mean?

Comment: "Running an aspx page in an asp page" also doesn't make sense - do you mean you're trying to pass data from a classic asp page to an asp.net page

Comment: I am sending data from classic asp page to asp.net page with ajaxSubmit.
So data trading in asp.net page.This process take long time like 20 second.

Comment: I am sending data from classic asp page to asp.net page with ajaxSubmit.
So data trading in asp.net page.This process take long time like 20 second.I want to print something during this process. But what I do prints out at the end of the process.